# Laravel request validation - nullable image

Tags: laravel, validation

I have registration form with username, email, password and avatar(image) fields. Everything works except image filed, which can be null. I am using Vue as front-end and send data with axios to Laravel.

This is validation:

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'username' => 'required|string|max:255|unique:users',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6',
        'avatar' => 'nullable|image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png|max:1999'
    ]);

    $fileNameToStore = 'noimage.jpg';

    return User::create([
        'username' => $request->username,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
        'avatar' => $fileNameToStore
    ]);
}
```

And this is how I send data:

```
register(context, data) {
      let formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('avatar', data.avatar)
      formData.append('username', data.username)
      formData.append('email', data.email)
      formData.append('password', data.password)

      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios.post('/register', formData,{
          headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
          }
        })
          .then(response => {
            resolve(response)
          })
          .catch(error => {
            reject(error)
          })
      })
}
```

If I fill out every filed it works fine and also other things like checking extension or file size works, only problem is when I don't select any image. I have nullable included in validation, but I still get error message from validation that it must be an image and which extension it needs to have.

Comment: What is the value of `data.avatar`?

Comment: Content-Disposition: form-data; name="avatar"

null

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your `data.avatar` is undefined or null, your server will eiter receive a `undefined` or `null` string as a value for your avatar field. Therefore, Laravel will be testing the image rule on the string.

To fix it, you can make sure your image is not undefined to send it in your request.

```
if (data.avatar) {
    formData.append('avatar', data.avatar);
}
```

Or

```
formData.append('avatar', data.avatar ?? '');
```

Comment: formData.append('avatar', data.avatar ??  ''); slightly shorter

Answer (score 0):

this is because of `data.avatar` send to backend as an empty string and 
you can write a `watch` for `data.avatar`, which every time `data.avatar` is empty string change it to null . like the following code :

```
watch(){
   'data.avatar'(value){
        if(value == '' || value == undefined){
             this.data.avatar = null 
          }
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did mine and it worked for me very well, I just added a **ref** attribute on the **input** that should be the user avatar and then retrieved the value of the input through Vue as follows `this.$refs.photo.files[0]`:

In my HTML using Vue

```
<input id="image" class="opacity-0" type="file" ref="photo">
```

and in my js using Vue

```
var data = new formData();


if(this.$refs.photo.files.length > 0)
   data.append('photo', this.$refs.photo.files[0]);

axios.post(...).then(...);
```